# Powershell - how do I list files and write their path into an output file?

Tags: file, powershell

I want to list *.xml files which are in several subdirectories. Then I want to write their path and their names into an txt file.
I managed to write the names into an txt file, however, I have no idea how to add their paths. What do I need to change/add?

```
Get-ChildItem path -recurse -include *.xml| ForEach-Object { $_.Name } > path\output.txt
```

Thank you for your help!
Cheers, 
Iris

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FullName will print the full path to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem path -recurse -include *.xml| ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } > path\output.txt
```

Here's a list of properties that the object returned in this instance provides: [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class